# Working with Alamofire for uploading image by using UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, alamofire

I am using UITabBarController in my application.Lets say survey form with steps,So each TabItem are step.At Step 3(Tab 3) there is an attachment which is photo upload using UIImagePickerController like this.

```
import UIKit

class AttachmentViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var photoCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var photo = [Photo]()

//..... Collection View Delegate and Datasource for displaying images

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    var newImage: UIImage

    if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else {
        return
    }

    let imageName = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

    if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 80) {
        jpegData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
    }

    let finalPhoto = Photo(image: imageName)
    photo.append(finalPhoto)
    photoCollectionView.reloadData()

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem is i don't know how to upload image with bytes using Alamofire in swift.I can get the image now,i just don't know how to upload it using alamofire.

Answer (score 0):

convert to base64 string and upload

```
 let image : UIImage = UIImage("your image")
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)
            base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```